# Filtering row data based off column values in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So I am able to get what I want if I only filter by one item, but can't figure out how to filter by two items. 
Basically I have a data set with a potential of unlimited rows but have 26 columns. I want to filter row data based on column data on columns A and B but only want the data in C and D to be returned only If A AND B match the values passed into the function. A and B values will be different but specified by being passed into the function.

It seems simple to me but when I try to run the second filter on the first filtered df my returned df is empty.

Comment: Could you please provide sample data and the expected results, so one could propose a solution?

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3,4], "B":[7,6,5,4], "C":[9,8,7,6], "D":[0,1,0,1]})
>>> df = df.loc[(df.A>1) & (df.B>4), ["C", "D"]]
>>> print(df)

   C  D
1  8  1
2  7  0
```